# Display the required error message in new lines within a box

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

This is regarding the display of required field message diaply.
Now i am displaying only the message "Entered phone format is not valid". This is taking the following css while running

```
    .formError .formErrorContent
    {
width: 100%;
background: #ee0101;
color: #fff;
width: 150px;
font-family: tahoma;
font-size: 11px;
border: 2px solid #ddd;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
display:inline;
height:auto;
}
```

But i want to add 3 more new lines to this error message like(enter 5 digits,no special characters etc)
But when i included those lines as follows

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Entered phone format is not valid. <br/> 5 digits are required.<br/> No special chars .    <br/> Numbers only")]
```

I am getting the 4 lines in 4 different message boxes, not in single message box.
Can anybody please hel me to dispaly this 4 messages ina single box with each in new lines.

Thanks,
Vidya

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: No this question is not related to CSS..something you have to change in presentation on controller layer as per ur app implementation

Comment: doesn't look like problem with MVC either, (am nt good with css but )try removing `display:inline`